# Seeking faster alternative to arcpy.Statistics_analysis?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, performance, statistics

I'm using **arcpy.Statistics_analysis** to count records and it takes about 30/35min for a table with about 6.8 million records, in a bigger script, this is a big chunk of the whole time.
The result of the 6.8M records is a 4.3M table, I was wondering if there's a faster alternative, maybe with some cursors?

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(FC, OUTPUT,[["Field1","COUNT"],["Field2","SUM"]],["Field1"])
```

**FC looks like:**

| Field0 | Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |

**OUTPUT would look like, with Statistics**

| Field1 | FREQUENCY | SUM_Field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Did you try building an index on `field1,field2` first? In a PostgreSQL database, a GROUP BY sum query with an index on 7M rows would take just seconds. Then there's the `memory` workspace option. Lots of ways to do this., even a DA SearchCursor with a dictionary.

Comment: Sounds very much like the bottle neck is not the tool but the data, I would expect the tool to complete within 1min with that number of rows.  I would explore adding attribute indices and where it is you are reading the data from and writing too. In memory would be quickest as would a local SSD drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I am using Pandas, to do a job quickly:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
inTable=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
caseField=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
theFields=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2).split(";")
outTable=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
usePandas=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
env.overwriteOutput = True
aTypes=["SUM"]

if usePandas=='false':
    arcpy.AddMessage("Using ArcGIS")
    if len(theFields[0]):
        stats=[[field, "SUM"] for field in theFields]
        arcpy.analysis.Statistics(inTable,outTable,stats,caseField)
    else:
        arcpy.analysis.Frequency(inTable,outTable,caseField)
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Using Pandas")
    fldSource=arcpy.ListFields(inTable)
    sourceNames=[row.name for row in fldSource]
    i=sourceNames.index(caseField)
    fld=fldSource[i]
    theType = fld.type
    import pandas as pd
    import string, random,os
    csv=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
    outCSV='F:/scratch/%s.csv'%csv
    if len(theFields[0]):
        tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inTable,[caseField]+theFields)
        df=pd.DataFrame(tbl);del tbl
        df["Frequency"]=1
        fList=["Frequency"]+theFields
    else:
        tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inTable,caseField)
        df=pd.DataFrame(tbl);del tbl
        df["Frequency"]=1
        fList=["Frequency"]
    sums=df.groupby([caseField])[fList].sum()
    del df
    if theType=='String':
        outINI='F:/scratch/schema.ini'
        f = open(outINI, "w")
        f.write('[%s.csv]\n' %csv)
        f.write('Col1=%s Text' %caseField)
        f.close()            
    arcpy.AddMessage(sums.head())
    sums.to_csv (outCSV,header=True)
    GDB,tbl=os.path.split(outTable)


    arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(outCSV, GDB, tbl)
    arcpy.management.Delete(outCSV)
```

The code could be much-much shorter, but ArcGIS has a mysterious ways of dealing with CSV files.

For a set of about 800Krecords, Pandas is 5.5 times faster, but slightly slower for tiny datasets.